# Python: Importing a private repo branch as a package module

Tags: python, git, package

Javascript Developer here. I'm working with a Python team and have a module to create and then have available for team use.

Requirements
Private Github Repo
Package is NOT public
Package is exported from a branch on the one repo
Package is imported from said branch on other peoples personal branches

Is this possible? I had tried the following:

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/(company-name-here)/(repo-name-here)@compression-module
```

I received the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ph2xb8tc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-ph2xb8tc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-3cw8ikqs
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-ph2xb8tc/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-build-ph2xb8tc/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
```

It would seem that it attempts to clone, checkout, switch branches, but then fails after that point. I think I am on the right track but...?

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
https://{username}:{password}@github.com/(company-name-here)/(repo-name-here)@compression-module
```

password: here can be an token or your account password.

but recommended is to use a token.

You can create a token from here https://github.com/settings/tokens

go to settings > developer settings > personal token

Comment: This produces the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that as my first time creating a python module I used a third party library called setuptools and needed some additional configuration.

Following this got it worked out :)
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html